# Eyelashes in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, node-editor

Looking at the picture below, where would I need to go to make his eyelashes look like eyelashes?
[image]
Pictures of the node setup would be appreciated because simply explaining confuses me sometimes

Thanks! :D

Comment: You could make a particle system and use hair

Comment: Alright so what would I need to include? Because I've never used hair before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- When you open Blender, then on the right (properties panel) you have
  to click the button with stars (particle system tab) (between physics tab and textures tab)
  [image]
- Then press 'new', under 'type' change from 'emitter' to 'hair'
  [image][image]
- Change the 'hair length' to any value you want
  [image]
- Make a new material (Materials tab)  and use the 'hair node' and play with the settings
  [image]
- (particle systems tab) In 'children', choose 'interpolated' and play with the 'render' values, set the 'display' value low, else Blender will react slow.
  [image]
- press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> to enter weight paint mode and paint where you want the hair
- Under Vertex Groups, choose under density the Group
  [image]
- Then under Cycles Hair Settings, play with the Root, Tip and scaling values
  [image]
- And for the final touch: enter 'Particle edit' to cut, comb, add,
  shrink, etc the hair. Have fun :)
  [image]

Comment: Thanks for this, but its kinda complicated though. Because I don't have to actually make the hair, i've got the image textures provided for me. Someone mentioned using alpha information to determine what part of the texture needs to be visible and invisible, but I don't know how to do it. So just the simple image at the top is the diffuse map for the eyelashes. Sorry, i'm really terrible with cycles :/

Comment: Use alpha as the factor to mix a diffuse and transparent shader

Comment: @user14621 Please mark this answer as accepted when it worked for you (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)